# How to get textbox value in ASP.NET click eventhandler

Tags: asp.net, postback, buttonclick

Somehow one of my stored procedures just stopped executing from aspx page. It works if I run it from SQL Server using `EXEC`. But when I click a button on my aspx page which assigns parameters and values, and launches this procedure, page reloads but data is not updated. This button can run create or update procedure, depending on the page parameters in the address bar. But nothing is executed.

In the aspx page I create that button like this:

```
<asp:Button id="btnSaveChanges" runat="server" 
     class="class_Button Normal Enabled" 
     OnClick="btnSaveChanges_Click" Text="Save changes" Width="100" />
```

Then in the code-behind file:

```
protected void btnSaveChanges_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (Page.IsValid)
    //{ 
        SqlCommand sqlComm1 = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection sqlConn1 = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\SqlExpress;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=true");

        sqlConn1.Open();

        if(param_id == 0) 
        {
           sqlComm1 = new SqlCommand("dcspCreateEmpDetails", sqlConn1);
        }

        if(param_id > 0) 
        {
            sqlComm1 = new SqlCommand("dcspUpdateEmpDetails", sqlConn1);
        }

        sqlComm1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (param_id > 0) 
            sqlComm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", param_id); 

        sqlComm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empName1", tbName1.Text);
        sqlComm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empSurname", tbSurname.Text);
        sqlComm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empBirthDate", Convert.ToDateTime(tbBirthDate.Text));

        sqlComm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //}
    sqlConn1.Close();
}
```

That's it. Page is valid, 100%. And even if I remove validation check, no result.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dcspUpdateEmpDetails
    @empID int,
    @empName1 nvarchar(50) = null,
    @empSurname nvarchar(50) = null,
    @empBirthDate datetime = null
AS
    UPDATE Employees 
    SET 
       name_1 = @empName1,
       surname = @empSurname,
       date_of_birth = @empBirthDate
    WHERE (employee_id = @empID)
```

Hope you'll help me with it, guys. I really don't understand what happened to this stuff...

**Updates for the topic:**

Examining debug messages I found, that textbox loses its text before the stored procedure in the `OnClick` event takes this text as a parameter.

Is it really normal that server first restores the page and only after that it executes code in `OnClick` event? I think it's logically incorrect because `Page_Load` is designed to load the default page, while buttons and other controls are used to change and manipulate content of a page. Why do I need those controls if their code can't execute timely?

Comment: There are two possible stored procedures here, Update and Create. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to make sure the SP you are expecting to execute is the one actually being executed? Also, why not add a try/catch block and trap any exceptions? Made sure that the parameter values are good?

Comment: Also, where is `param_id` declared?

Comment: what i have found in your code sqlConn1.close is out side the if statement and its declared inside the if block. which will through design time error..

Comment: If the backup copy works, and is identical in all the places concerning the function, then you need to look at the other differences. It sounds like the page is not posting back properly.

Comment: Did you make sure your connection string is good?

Comment: `Examining debug messages I found, that textbox loses its text `. I've edited the question title and have retagged accordingly.

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like you're resetting the controls in the `Page_Load` event. If that's the case, you need to wrap the updates in an `if (!IsPostBack) { ... }` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took my backup copy and copied all stuff regarding this problem to my current version. It was just the same absolutely identical code. I just replaced current code with the same code from backup and it works now. What was that?

I can't mark anything as an answer because there are only comments here. I'll mark this one.